# search for known logotype(s) in an image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'd love to write a program that will take a scanned invoice (original is A4 paper, scanned as JPEG file (wrapped in a PDF), ~4000 pixels wide) and look for logotypes. If a logotype is found, the invoice file (PDF) will be tagged with those tags associated with the logotypes found in the invoice.

I expect 20 or so logotypes to look for, and about 2500 invoices (so yes, a pain to do manually).

My ideas are drawn towards OpenCV since I know that's used behind the scenes by Sikuli. I would only look for logos in certain areas, ie logo A should only be looked for in top left corner of every invoice, logo B top right etc. Dropping the JPG to monochrome with high contrast I assume would help too?

Comment: Can you provide some of your input and output images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"20 or so logotypes" is a good number to use keypoints (corners, blobs etc) and it's descriptors(SIFT, SURF, FREAK etc) in find-nearest-neighbor-way. Steps are:

## 1 train

- create a training set of logo (take it from your documents)
- calculate a set of keypoints and it's descriptors for every logo

## 2 find

- do picture equalization and noise filtering
- find keypoints and it's descriptors
- find best matching descriptors (find nearest neighbor) in you training set
- find homography for matching keypoints position to be sure it is a complete logo but not just one accidental point

All this steps are implemented in openCV. But you will need some time to play with parameters to have the best solution. Anyway you have very low level of logo distortion so you will have high level of "True Positive" results and low level of "False Positive" ones.